# Why does Chrome introduce extra space inside scaled elements when printing?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing

In Chrome, when a div is scaled down, things look fine, until I click print. After clicking print, extra spaces are added in random places. If the space is inside text, it will be the height of a line, or if it is introduced before an image, it will be the same height as the image.

I have a simple example, which is simply text in a div. At first, the example looks correct; but after clicking print, the print preview adds in a space in the second paragraph which remains after the print dialog is closed.

This behaviour doesn't occur in Firefox or IE.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5tovueyt/1/

HTML Code:

```
<a href="javascript:window.print();">Print</a>
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis molestie, mi vitae tincidunt posuere, est lorem dictum dolor, et sollicitudin leo felis at mauris. Ut finibus rutrum leo, vel tristique purus maximus a. Curabitur vitae lacinia lacus, at ornare neque. Integer ut fringilla libero. Donec tristique quam eget diam convallis, vitae sollicitudin lectus malesuada. Vestibulum euismod at ligula ut malesuada. Praesent tempor, dui vitae semper imperdiet, risus arcu auctor ligula, in commodo quam metus in eros. Sed non nibh a lorem auctor congue sit amet sed mauris. Sed molestie ullamcorper lacinia. Praesent pharetra felis mollis orci consequat, et dapibus purus condimentum.
<br><br>
Maecenas lobortis elit eu eleifend facilisis. Ut quis facilisis lorem. Integer dapibus lectus nec turpis vehicula posuere. Vestibulum mattis ac nisi sed dictum. Fusce placerat massa sit amet urna lacinia, vitae posuere turpis hendrerit. In blandit, orci mattis rhoncus elementum, arcu dui elementum nisi, at luctus urna mi non leo. Nulla ullamcorper et leo ut bibendum. Praesent et lectus sapien.
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    font-size: 48pt;
    transform: scale(0.25);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    width: 2000px;
}
```

Before clicking print:

[image: Before clicking print]

After clicking print: (extra space highlighted in red)

[image]

Does anyone know why this happens? Is this a bug in Chrome? Is there anyway to prevent this occurring?